# Issue with height: 100% and nested div

Tags: css, html, height

I know that is a popular problem, but I really ca't find a solution..
here my jsfiddle
       http://jsfiddle.net/vUqer/
As you can see, the

```
  div id="layoutdueColonne"
```

go outside the

```
  div id="content"
```

Why?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `height` and `min-height` in `content` and `layoutdueColonne`. When you remove them and add

```
#content
{
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You will see both `sq1` and `sq2` inside `content`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUqer/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The float left and right for sq1 and sq2 causes this problem. As workaround, try to combine the two tables into one table or just accept the two tables to be vertically arranged.

Comment: my idea was to use the combination of two table into one table, but I read that using tables for layout is incorrect. But if this is the only way to obtain my 2 divs horizontally arranged I'll use tables...

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, it is workaround, so may be another solution. Also, the table you use is not layout tables, it is just tabular data!

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

```
overflow:scroll;
```

to your content div solve the problem, or am I missing something else?

http://jsfiddle.net/vUqer/2/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't resolve my problem... and I don't want two scrollbar anyway...